# chdir in .screenrc on mac

Tags: macos, gnu-screen, chdir, screenrc

I could chdir in .screenrc in linux
so that when I open up screen, I could go to specified directory(for each tab)

Haven't had success with chdir in mac with screenrc.
Anyone have done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. What does your  `chdir` command look like, and what happens when you run `screen`?

Comment: shell -$SHELL which was copied from linux was the cause.. now it chdir correctly. but the terminal reads bash-3.2$ instead of {dir_name}$ .

Comment: removing shell -${SHELL} worked for me on cygwin as well.  Thanks!